# Which one is appropriate when describing belonging?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

Talking of memory, which is correct?

> To my heart

Or

> In my heart

If talking of belonging, which one is correct?

> She always belong to my heart

Or

> She's always in my heart

Can I use "always to my heart" without indicating "belong"?

Comment: No, "to my heart" is not idiomatic. "belong to" is a phrasal verb, you can't just use "to" by itself.

Comment: I'd have gone for ***always in my thoughts***, but apparently [***in my heart*** is more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+in+my+thoughts%2Calways+in+my+heart&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20)

Comment: Can you put each example into a whole sentence, please? Further, while 'She's always in my heart' is undoubtedly correct, 'She always belong to my heart' might well work in poetry, provided you put back the missing 's'.

Meanwhile, 'She always belong to my heart' and 'She's always in my heart' are merely co-incidental choices; not usefully comparable.

Are you hoping to compare 'She always belongs to my heart' with 'She's always belongs in my heart' or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Barmar answered:

> No, "to my heart" is not idiomatic. "belong to" is a phrasal verb, you can't just use "to" by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Fumblefingers answered:

> I'd have gone for ***always in my thoughts***, but apparently [***in my heart*** is more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+in+my+thoughts%2Calways+in+my+heart&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20)